# passing string parameter from js view to controller

Tags: javascript, c#

Below mentioned function is getting "value" from "
      Status
      Lead
      General"

```
function mypage (value) { 

    var x=value;
        if(x=="Lead") {

            var y = value;
            window.location = '@Url.Action("tagWiseContacts", "Status",new {y=value})'

        }
```

I want to pass the "value" as parameter to a function in the Controller, but it's working,I also tried other methods too.

Comment: It is MVC Framework? If so, please add the related tag.

Answer (score 0):

As in your case, server side code rendered first.
You need to use ajax call to pass parameter to server side.

```
$.get(url:'@Url.Action("tagWiseContacts", "Status")', data: {y: value})
```